# Any information about this error

Tags: java, unix, oracle10g

Application(Java/J2ee) is using Oracle Application server 10g running in RHEL 5 OS.
Any help will be appreciate

```
Exception Name: com.evermind.server.rmi.OrionRemoteException
Exception Message: Transaction was rolled back: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.RemoteException: ; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
Exception Stack Trace: com.evermind.server.rmi.OrionRemoteException: Transaction was rolled back: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
    at ToolFacadeRemote_StatelessSessionBeanWrapper32.getLocatorOutput(ToolFacadeRemote_StatelessSessionBeanWrapper32.java:152)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
at com.f1j.swing.JBook.<init>(DashoA8533)
at com.f1j.swing.JBook.<init>(DashoA8533)
```

Comment: This isn't the best sort of question for StackOverflow as it doesn't really fit into the Q&A format.  In particular I think it's unlikely to help other people in future - at least with the current dearth of details.

Answer (score 0):

It's a `NoClassDefFoundError`, as you can see from the stacktrace.  This means that a class required by the application is not on the classpath.

Ensure that all the requierd classes and JARs are on the application server's classpath (possible in a WAR/EAR, or accessible via RMI's remote codepath, depending on how your application infrastructure works).

Answer (score 0):

More specifically, it means a class you need during your database handling code is missing from the Java classpath (that's where you can start looking in your code base).